# Find the coordinates of square at client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an image on my page which I can fetch via $('#myimage'); Now I want to find the coordinates of square which I will draw on image. These end points of square should be exactly such that radius of square should be 20px(the center of the square will be center  of image). How can I get do the same with JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dims = {x: 20, y: 20},
    obj = $('#myImage'),
    img = obj.offset(),
    coords = {top: img.top + (obj.height()-dims.y)/2,
              left: img.left + (obj.width()-dims.x)/2};
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/22TMD/

You can use `position()` instead of `offset()` if you want it relative to the offset parent and not the document (depends on how you're going to add the square in the markup). So too, you can use `innerHeight()` and `outerHeight()` depending on the styling of the image.